Is it possible to use some sort of a temporary table with a lifespan of a query?
I have the following table that I generate with a certain query:
+-------------+------------------+
| error_codes | number_of_orders |
+-------------+------------------+
| 2066        |              104 |
| 5092        |              642 |
+-------------+------------------+

I'd like to append the corresponding message for each and every error. The error message table does not exist but I hope it's possible to create a temporary one within a query which will be destroyed as soon as the query is complete.
+-------------+------------------+
| error_codes | error_message    |
+-------------+------------------+
| 2066        |         Tralalala|
| 5092        |         Ohje     |
+-------------+------------------+

Given the uniqueness of the error codes it can be used as the index to join the tables on. But the point is that I don't want this table in the DB, it should be a virtual table or something of the sort.
The end result is expected to look as follows:
+--------------------------------+--------------+
| error_codes | number_of_orders | error_message|                                                                          
+-------------+------------------+--------------+
| 2066        |              104 | Tralalala    |
| 5092        |              642 | Ohje         |
+-------------+------------------+--------------+



Did you try using a Common Table Expression (CTE) in your query to create a virtual table containing the error messages ? Check this link
A simple usage example :
WITH ErrorMessages AS (
    SELECT 2066 AS error_codes, 'Tralalala' AS error_message
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5092 AS error_codes, 'Ohje' AS error_message
)
SELECT 
    e.error_codes, 
    e.number_of_orders,
    em.error_message
FROM 
    your_table_name e
JOIN 
    ErrorMessages em ON e.error_codes = em.error_codes;


Somewhat more directly relevant link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html

Looks just nigh on perfect! Thanks a ton!

I upvoted the other answer suggesting using a CTE, but here's another solution:
SELECT 
    e.error_codes, 
    e.number_of_orders,
    em.error_message
FROM 
    your_table_name e
NATURAL JOIN (
    VALUES ROW(2066, 'Tralalala'), ROW(5092, 'Ohje')
) AS em(error_codes, error_message);

This uses the VALUES statement which is a new feature in MySQL 8.0.
This is also a rare example of using NATURAL JOIN.

Wow, amazing trick. Thanks a lot! I didn't know about this sort of join. I will read on it.
